# IF Formula to return value only if A1=A2, B1=B2

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am currently stuck with the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",
IF(AND(A1=C1,B1=D1),5,
IF(OR(C1-D1=A1-B1,AND(C1>D1,A1>B1),
AND(D1>C1,B1>A1)),2,0)))
```

The premise behind this is that:
A1 and B1 are the actual real life scores in my tournament. 
C1 and D1 are the predicted scores.

If the scores are correct, 5 points are given, if the result is correct, 2 points are given.

As the scoring depends on the correct teams, I need the above points to be given only if E1=F1 AND G1=H1.

I have tried to add IF(AND(E1=F1,G1=H1) throughout this formula but it doesn't seem to work. It either comes back as an error or it says too many arguments have been entered. I don't seem to be putting it in the right place.

Comment: My advice here would be to rewrite your question and instead of showing a long formula with cell/sheet references, just use variables, either `x` or `y`, or maybe `A1`, just a dummy cell.  This will make it much easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Should I re-write it here or post it as a new question?

Comment: You should rewrite / edit this question and provide a clear example of the data with what you are trying to achieve. I have shown an example of the basic question involving IF() with AND() for you.

Comment: Don't rewrite, just add your current formula using letters as variables.

Comment: Okay will do, thanks guys.

Comment: I have edited, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to follow what you have as the data is not there to show what you are testing, the answer to your and question at the end is as follows, D1 has the formula working, D2 shows the formula.

[image: IF with AND example]

You should be able to expand this to suit your needs.

Comment: I have edited above if you could please advise Mike.

Comment: I have given you a working example, have you tried expanding it one step at a time?

Comment: I think I need to know what to put if the true and false values to ensure that the rest of the formula is followed